# C++ index out of range NOT occurring when it should

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, copy

I'm trying to write a OBJMesh loader at the moment in DirectX and I came across a problem with a section of my code:

```
unsigned int vertexCount = vertexData.size();
VERTEX* vertices = new VERTEX[vertexCount];
std::copy(vertexData.begin(), vertexData.end(), vertices);
```

The `vertexData` in the `std::copy` is a `vector<VERTEX>` and I'm trying to copy the data in vertexData to my newly created vertices array.

when I load in my objmesh file, I have checked there are 2841 vertices which is correct and I've stored it to vertexCount (I've checked it by doing a `std::cout << vertexCount`).

However, the real problem is that when I check the data and size of the array by entering `std::cout << vertices[3000].x` it prints out something without triggering the **index out of bound** error.

Knowing I've created the vertices array with a size of 2841, the compiler should stop and display a error should it not? What exactly is the problem and why is it behaving like this??

Please help

**EDIT:**
using Visual Studio 2010
Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Which compiler? Which operating system? Many compilers have some ways to enable "checked" iterators and indexing functions.

Comment: Which part of the standard supports your claim that your program should crash and display an error?

Comment: Out of bounds access here is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Literally the 3rd identical question today...

Comment: Your vertices are just an ordinary array. No bound checking.

Comment: And also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1239977/2494803)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of `vertices[3000].x` is [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The compiler/runtime are not obliged to provide any diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing an element beyond the end of an array in C++ is undefined behavior. That basically means that anything can happen and that you should not be expecting any particular result or error.

Answer (score 0):

What you do leads to undefined behavior. anything can happen, you can absolutely not expect out of bounds exception. Which you could realistically get only if used `std::vector` and accessed elements using .at() instead of [].